# Why is the React `MouseEvent` in the checkbox event handler not generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, types, jsx

I have an checkbox TSX(JSX) element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name={i.toString()} onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

With the help of VS code I know that the input parameter type of the `this.handleCheckboxClick` is `MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>`. So I implemented it with:

```
private handleCheckboxClick(event: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    ...
}
```

Then I get an error saying `[ts] Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic.` As shown in the image below:

[image]

Version of my packages:

```
"@types/react": "^15.0.29",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"typescript": "^2.3.4",
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 537, accepted):

You're probably using the DOM `MouseEvent`. Try using `React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>` instead.

Comment: Not working for me, I get: `type: "checkbox" onChange: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; defaultChec...' is not assignable to type 'InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'`

Comment: @Kokodoko did you ever fix this?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me on my way! my click event now looks like `clickHandler?: (event?: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, Event>) => void;` - hopefully that helps someone else :)

Answer (score 41):

In order to use React MouseEvent just make sure to add:

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

Comment: Also worked with a similar problem that I was having with KeyboardEvent. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use SyntheticEvent instead of MouseEvent

Answer (score 4):

You just need to check if you are importing your event from React.

```
import { MouseEvent, MouseEventHandler } from 'react';
```